# shell: how to pagination file with code highlight?

Tags: shell, unix, syntax-highlighting, less-unix

I was checking that you can highlight code with `pygmentize` like:

```
pygmentize -g mycodefile
```

but for large files, I would like the ability to paginate the files like with `less` or `more`, but when I try:

```
pygmentize -g mycodefile | less
```

The output is not correct, example:

```
ESC[34mfromESC[39;49;00m ESC[04mESC[36mmodule
```

How can I paginate a file in shell with code highlight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
pygmentize -g mycodefile | less -R
```

so `less` shows ANSI colour sequences.

Comment: Great, that was it. Thanks